What is the most likely form of John 1:1 in Hebrew?
Since Hebrew has different words for "God" John 1:1 could have been more precise than the Greek.

In the beginning was the Word and the Word was with Elohim and the Word was Elohim


In the beginning was the Word and the Word was with El and the Word was El


In the beginning was the Word and the Word was with Elohim and the Word was El

What is the most likely form of John 1:1 in Hebrew?


The question as asked is entirely opinion based. "Since Hebrew has different words for "God" John 1:1 could have been more precise than the Greek" - is "could have been" assuming/speculating that John was originally written in Hebrew? Because otherwise you can answer your own question by looking at a Hebrew translation of the New Testament

@AviAvraham A Hebrew translation from the Greek is a different approach than an original Hebrew, for exactly the reasons I show. A writer in Hebrew has three words from which to choose to render the statement, a writer in Greek has one.

I think you could also include the singular Eloah because it comes into play for why Elohim is significant.

@RevelationLad. Your question insinuates polytheism. If Elohim is taken as the Father/ YHWH is the God the word was with, and El was the word. That makes two gods. One called Elohim the other El. IThis question is trying to put the idea of a multi -person God in this verse.

This question is based on the assumption that John was originally written in Hebrew which in untrue.  Otherwise, several translations of John into Hebrew are readily available.

@AlexBalilo What an interesting comment. Polytheism for asking about which Hebrew word to use? There are over 40 verses in the OT which have both Elohim and El. How is asking about a common OT composition polytheism? Unless you believe the OT is polytheistic. On the contrary using Elohim and El would make a clear distinctions between the two, just as is done in the OT.

@RevelationLad. Who is the God that the word was with? And if you say that the word was El, that makes two Gods, does it not? If you say Elohim, is God and El is God too, that makes 2 Gods.

@AlexBalilo I fail to see how a NT writer using the OT vorlage produces a different meaning than it does in the OT. There is no real issue since Elohim and El can be translated as God or god. So El in way gives a better justification for “god.” The issue is in your mind because it does look like polytheism, exactly as it does in the OT. One you accept the other you see as a problem, but they would be the same.

@RevelationLad. How are they the same when the verse say "the word was with God"? The verse does not say the God was with the God.

The Hebrew New Testament says:

This can be transliterated as:

Bereshit hayah hadavar vehadavar hayah et ha'Elohim vElohim hayah
hadavar.

In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with Elohim (אלהים), and the Word was Elohim (אֱלֹהִים; θεός). [6]


El: This is a generic term for “god” in ancient Semitic languages,
including Hebrew [1]. It’s often used, in the Hebrew Bible, in compound
names for God, such as “El Shaddai” (God Almighty) and “El Elyon”
(God Most High) [1][2]. The term “El” emphasizes the power and might of
God [4].
Elohim: ’Elohim is the plural of ’Eloah. This form is often described as a plural of
majesty, used to indicate the all-inclusiveness of God’s authority as
possessing every conceivable attribute of power [1][3]. It’s used more
frequently in the Hebrew Bible than “El”, and it’s the term used in
Genesis 1:1, which parallels the “in the beginning” of John 1:1 [1][5].
It would make sense then that using “Elohim” in John 1:1 could therefore create a literary and
theological link between these two foundational passages.


What are the literary and theological link between the passages you cited? If Elohim is plural a plural of majesty, does it mean then that it Elohim conveys plurality of Gods?

If Elohim rather than El, then then the intent is to identify the Word in the same manner as God, Elohim. Therefore, if not El, then the intent is to avoid an identification which could be taken as not Elohim. IOW, a writer who uses the same term for both not only identifies each with the same term, they also indicate a stronger intent to do so since they could have expressed a similar though by using El for the Word. A stronger way of saying the Word was God, Elohim, not the Word was god, el.

@RevelationLad."Even a single heathen god can be designated as Elohim. Is it "therefore, if if not El, then the intent is to avoid an identification which could be taken as not Elohim. IOW, a writer who uses the same term for both not only identifies each with the same term, they also indicate a stronger intent to do so since they could have expressed a similar though by using El for" Chemosh?

אֱלֹהִ֑ים is in Gen 1:1 thus uses for God in Hebrew New Testament translations.  In the two Hebrew translations I'm looking at הַדָּבָר is "the Word."
However, here is an interesting discussion:

...but where did John get the idea that “the Word” could refer to God as a person?  The answer lies partly in the translation John used....These Aramaic translations are called Targums. One specific Targum of the Pentateuch, Targum Onqelos, was sanctioned by Jewish religious authorities for use in the synagogue.
The Targums telegraph the idea of God as “Word” in many places—in vivid, sometimes startling ways. Many Jews of John’s day would have been familiar with the idea. The Aramaic term for “word,” memra, was often used as another way to refer to God. Consider Numbers 14:11 in the ESV and from Targum Neofiti, noting the words in bold:



John wrote his gospel in Greek, but his theology was Jewish, conveyed to him through Aramaic. Therefore, both Jews and non-Jewish people got the point in unmistakable terms: The Word of the Old Testament had been made flesh (John 1:14) and walked among us.
--
Heiser, M. S. (2017). The Bible Unfiltered: Approaching Scripture on Its Own Terms (p. 166-168). Lexham Press.


When the OT uses the plural of elohim about a group of gods, the New Testament quotation of that verse show theous (gods) plural instead of theos (god) singular.Psalm 82:6; John 10:35; Exodus 32:1 and Acts 7:40.
When the Old Testament uses "elohim" about YHVH, the New Testament cites that verse using the singular "theos" as shown in Deuterony 6:4 Mark 12:29 to show that the writers of the New Testament did not view elohim as a plural being.
If the New Testament used theos for the Hebrew Elohim in this verse, then it shows that the Elohim here is singular. Since the word was with Elohim, the word could not be the same Elohim (plural of majesty) that he was with. The "word" then is a separate entity
Taken literally, "elohim" indicates a plurality of gods, not a plurality of persons.
Here are some comments about elohim.
"Elohim, when used for God, is most emphatically singular in meaning,"-Zondervan Pictorial Encyclopedia of the Bible.
When God is titled "elohim" in the Bible, words used to refer to Him are singular- such as "Elohim, He", not "Elohim, They"."[When referring to God] the noun elohim is consistently used with singular verb forms and with adjective and pronouns in singular"-Theological Workbook of the Old Testament, v.1, p, 44, 1980
